# USB-Device, filesystems and inotify

Tags: linux, filesystems, usb, inotify, dd

I'm looking for a solution for being notified about files and directories modifications using inotify or any other API when the files are located on a file-system on a custom board that is configured as a USB device. My Linux is buildroot and deployed on a custom board. I've connected the board to a Host machine running Ubuntu. After creating the file-system on the board I can copy files into the target board with no problems. What I would like to achieve is to get notifications about changes in files and directories on the Linux OS running on the board where the file-system is located. For example, is someone is copying a txt file from the Ubuntu host into the mounted directory I will get a notification on the target board.

What I've been able to do so far is to be notified that a change on the file-system has occurred but could not achieve a specific notification about exactly what has changed. This is how I've accomplished that:

On the target board I've created a file based file-system using:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test bs=1M count=500
```

Then I created a file based file system out of it:

```
mkdosfs /tmp/test
```

Then I then started to listen to file-system events (on the target board) with:

```
inotifywait /tmp/test
```

Then I copied a foo.txt file onto the mounted directory on the Ubuntu Host side.

I then received a notification (on the target board) that /tmp/test has been modified.

What I want to achieve is to get notification about foo.txt on the board, and once I will be notified about that file I want to have access to it, also on the board. I have no problem if the final solution would be to get notifications about a predefined directory on the mounted file-system if that would be easier.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm asking?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not an inotify expert, but based on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait), it looks like you need something like `inotifywait -m -r /mnt/dosfs-mount-point`.